# How to pass javascript array to python flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm not really expert at javascript, but i have a school project where i need to use python flask to make a website.
the problem is that when i input on html, i put the value on javascript array, and then i need to send it to python where i can process the data. Anyone knows how?

Here's the code:
HTML:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>4 Years</title>
      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7006f68f03.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/category.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <img src="static/test.jpeg" height="70">
      <hr>
      <form class="content" action="/category/list" method="post" id="myform">
         <div class="genres-input">
            Genres:
            <div class="genres-box">
               <ul id="genreul">
                  <input class="input-text" type="text" name="genres" list="genre">
               </ul>
               <datalist id="genre">
                  <option value="Action"></option>
                  <option value="Adventure"></option>
                  <option value="Animation"></option>
                  <option value="Biography"></option>
                  <option value="Comedy"></option>
                  <option value="Crime"></option>
                  <option value="Documentary"></option>
                  <option value="Drama"></option>
                  <option value="Family"></option>
                  <option value="Fantasy"></option>
                  <option value="Film-Noir"></option>
                  <option value="Game-Show"></option>
                  <option value="History"></option>
                  <option value="Horror"></option>
                  <option value="Music"></option>
                  <option value="Musical"></option>
                  <option value="Mystery"></option>
                  <option value="News"></option>
                  <option value="Reality-TV"></option>
                  <option value="Romance"></option>
                  <option value="Sci-Fi"></option>
                  <option value="Short"></option>
                  <option value="Sport"></option>
                  <option value="Talk-Show"></option>
                  <option value="Thriller"></option>
                  <option value="War"></option>
                  <option value="Western"></option>
               </datalist>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="age-input">
            Ages:
            <div class="ages-box">
               <input class="input-text" type="number" name="ages" placeholder=" 0 - 99" min="0" max="99">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="keywords-input">
            Keywords:
            <div class="keywords-box">
               <ul id="keyul">
                  <input class="input-text" type="text" name="keywords">
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="type-input">
            Types:
            <div class="types-box">
               <input class="input-text" type="text" name="types" list="type">
               <datalist id="type">
                  <option value="Movie"></option>
                  <option value="TV Series"></option>
                  <option value="Short"></option>
                  <option value="TV Episode"></option>
                  <option value="TV Mini Series"></option>
                  <option value="TV Movie"></option>
                  <option value="TV Special"></option>
                  <option value="TV Short"></option>
                  <option value="Video Game"></option>
                  <option value="Video"></option>
                  <option value="Music Video"></option>
                  <option value="Podcast Series"></option>
                  <option value="Podcast Episode"></option>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="search">
            <input class="submit" onclick="search_value()" type="button" name="search" value="Search">
         </div>
      </form>
      <script src="static/category.js"></script>
      <script src="static/disable_enter.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var ul1 = document.querySelector("ul#genreul"),
input1 = ul1.querySelector("input");
let genre_list = [];
var ul2 = document.querySelector("ul#keyul"),
input2 = ul2.querySelector("input");
let keyword_list = [];
function createTag1(){
   ul1.querySelectorAll("li#genres").forEach(li => li.remove());
   console.log(keyword_list.slice().reverse());
   genre_list.slice().reverse().forEach(genre =>{
      let liTag1 = `<li id='genres'>${genre} <i class="fa-solid fa-x" onclick="remove1(this,'${genre}')"></i></li>`;
      ul1.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", liTag1);
   });
}
function createTag2(){
   ul2.querySelectorAll("li#keywords").forEach(li => li.remove());
   console.log(keyword_list.slice().reverse());
   keyword_list.slice().reverse().forEach(keyword =>{
      let liTag2 = `<li id='keywords'>${keyword} <i class="fa-solid fa-x" onclick="remove2(this,'${keyword}')"></i></li>`;
      ul2.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", liTag2);
   });
}
function remove1(element, genre){
   let index1 = genre_list.indexOf(genre);
   genre_list = [...genre_list.slice(0, index1), ...genre_list.slice(index1 + 1)];
   element.parentElement.remove();
}
function remove2(element, keyword){
   let index2 = keyword_list.indexOf(keyword);
   keyword_list = [...keyword_list.slice(0, index2), ...keyword_list.slice(index2 + 1)];
   element.parentElement.remove();
}
function addTag1(e){
   if(e.key == "Enter"){
      let genre = e.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(',','');
      if(genre.length > 1 && !genre_list.includes(genre)){
         genre_list.push(genre);
         createTag1();
      }
      e.target.value = "";
   }
}
function addTag2(e){
   if(e.key == "Enter"){
      let keyword = e.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(',','');
      if(keyword.length > 1 && !keyword_list.includes(keyword)){
         keyword_list.push(keyword);
         createTag2();
      }
      e.target.value = "";
   }
}
function search_value() {
   console.log(genre_list);
   console.log(keyword_list);
   document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
input1.addEventListener("keyup", addTag1);
input2.addEventListener("keyup", addTag2);
```

Python:

```
from flask import Blueprint,request,render_template
Category = Blueprint('category',__name__,static_folder='static',template_folder='templates')
@Category.route('/category')
def category_html():return render_template('category.html')
@Category.route('/category/list',methods=['POST','GET'])
def category_value():
   #genre =
   ages = request.form["ages"]
   #keyword = 
   types = request.form['types']
   print(ages,types)
   return render_template('list.html',text2=ages,text4=types)
```

from what i researched, i've tried to using xmlhttprequest(), but it seems didn't work well

Changed JS:

```
var ul1 = document.querySelector("ul#genreul"),
input1 = ul1.querySelector("input");
let genre_list = [];
var ul2 = document.querySelector("ul#keyul"),
input2 = ul2.querySelector("input");
let keyword_list = [];
function createTag1(){
   ul1.querySelectorAll("li#genres").forEach(li => li.remove());
   console.log(keyword_list.slice().reverse());
   genre_list.slice().reverse().forEach(genre =>{
      let liTag1 = `<li id='genres'>${genre} <i class="fa-solid fa-x" onclick="remove1(this,'${genre}')"></i></li>`;
      ul1.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", liTag1);
   });
}
function createTag2(){
   ul2.querySelectorAll("li#keywords").forEach(li => li.remove());
   console.log(keyword_list.slice().reverse());
   keyword_list.slice().reverse().forEach(keyword =>{
      let liTag2 = `<li id='keywords'>${keyword} <i class="fa-solid fa-x" onclick="remove2(this,'${keyword}')"></i></li>`;
      ul2.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", liTag2);
   });
}
function remove1(element, genre){
   let index1 = genre_list.indexOf(genre);
   genre_list = [...genre_list.slice(0, index1), ...genre_list.slice(index1 + 1)];
   element.parentElement.remove();
}
function remove2(element, keyword){
   let index2 = keyword_list.indexOf(keyword);
   keyword_list = [...keyword_list.slice(0, index2), ...keyword_list.slice(index2 + 1)];
   element.parentElement.remove();
}
function addTag1(e){
   if(e.key == "Enter"){
      let genre = e.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(',','');
      if(genre.length > 1 && !genre_list.includes(genre)){
         genre_list.push(genre);
         createTag1();
      }
      e.target.value = "";
   }
}
function addTag2(e){
   if(e.key == "Enter"){
      let keyword = e.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(',','');
      if(keyword.length > 1 && !keyword_list.includes(keyword)){
         keyword_list.push(keyword);
         createTag2();
      }
      e.target.value = "";
   }
}
function search_value() {
   console.log(genre_list);
   console.log(keyword_list);
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/category';
   xhr.open('POST', url, true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   var jsonData = JSON.stringify({ data: genre_list });
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
         console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
   };
   xhr.send(jsonData);
 }
 
 document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("submit", search_value);
 input1.addEventListener("keyup", addTag1);
 input2.addEventListener("keyup", addTag2);
```

Changed Python:

```
from flask import Blueprint,request,render_template
Category = Blueprint('category',__name__,static_folder='static',template_folder='templates')
@Category.route('/category')
def category_html():return render_template('category.html')
@Category.route('/category/list',methods=['POST','GET'])
def category_value():
   genre = request.get_json(force=True)
   print(genre)
   ages = request.form["ages"]
   #keyword = 
   types = request.form['types']
   print(ages,types)
   return render_template('list.html',text2=ages,text4=types)
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requests only handle strings. Even sending data via specs as commonplace as JSON involve the formatting of a string on the sender side (client) and parsing that string on the reciever side (server). Therefore, you don't send an array from your JS app to your python app, you send a string which your JS app formats and your Python app interprets.

Different web frameworks have different approaches for handling "array like" data. For example, some APIs interpret params sent in the format of `?tags[]=a&tags[]=b&tags=c` as the array `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Likewise, different client side libraries for making HTTP requests use different strategies for formatting/serializing data sent in a request.

In Flask, I believe you use the `form.getlist('tags[]')` method to pull a list out of a submitted form. This would be expecting your form inputs be configured with `name=tags[]` attribute. However, if you're sending JSON to the server, you can format it however you like. Just make sure that you are parsing the string into a JSON object in Flask before trying to access the property.

Also, it looks like you're making a POST request to your /category endpoint, when your Flask routes are set to accept POST requests at /category/list...

Comment: yeah i know we actually dont need javascript list to pass to python flask. But in my html code, i making something like tag, which is when i input, the value immidiately push to js list and the input become empty again, and it need to use javascript list. That's why i need to pass the js list to python flask. Did u got any ideas?

Comment: 1. In your search_value function, you're making a POST request to the wrong endpoint (it seems).

Comment: 2. The guard clause on your addTag functions looks off, as in it would never allow a tag to be added to the initial empty array.

Comment: 3. Really recommend trying to clean up your code. Try using the Fetch API as opposed to XHR. Refactor your li template(s) code into dedicated template functions. Add and remove functions do the exact same thing, so should be one function that take the list as an argument. Don't assign a duplicate id attribute to every tag.

Comment: already done arrange my code. By the way, what you mean POST request to the wrong endpoint. Sorry im kinda new to javascript

Comment: and btw, i saw many peeps using Node js to pass the js list. Is there any other way without using tha?. Cuz im afraid if i submit my homework project to teacher, it didnt run properly if the teacher didnt install that node js.
Also i saw some peeps using ajax, and im trying to use it.

Comment: This is your Python endpoint where you expect the list `@Category.route('/category/list',methods=['POST','GET'])`.  This is the endpoint your JS is sending the request to `var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/category';`

Answer (score 0):

To save you work with AJAX, it is possible to save the elements of the array with separators in a hidden input. So you can send the form in the usual way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="tag-input">
            <ul class="tags"></ul>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a tag" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tags" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        class TagsField {
            constructor(elem) {
                this.elem = elem;
                this.tags = elem.querySelector('.tags');
                this.input = elem.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
                this.hidden = elem.querySelector('input[type="hidden"]');
                this.#init();
            }
            #init() {
                this.#createTagsList(this.hidden.value !== '' ? this.hidden.value.split(';') : []);
                this.input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
                    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        let tagValue = this.input.value.trim();
                        let tagValues = this.hidden.value !== '' ? this.hidden.value.split(';') : [];
                        if (tagValue && !tagValues.includes(tagValue)) {
                            tagValues.push(tagValue);
                            this.#createTagsList(tagValues); 
                            this.hidden.value = tagValues.join(';');
                        }
                        this.input.value = '';
                    }
                });
            }
            #createTagsList(values) {
                this.tags.innerHTML = values.map(value => {
                    return `<li class="tag"><span class="value">${value}</span><button type="button">&times;</button></li>`;
                }).join('');
                this.tags.querySelectorAll('li.tag button').forEach(elem => {
                    elem.addEventListener('click', event => {
                        let target = event.target;
                        let value = target.parentElement.querySelector('.value').innerText;
                        let values = this.hidden.value.split(';');
                        values.splice(values.indexOf(value), 1);
                        this.hidden.value = values.join(';');
                        target.parentElement.remove();
                    });
                });
            }
        }

        (function() {
            const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.tag-input');
            elems.forEach(elem => new TagsField(elem));
        })();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can then separate the elements again on the server.

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template,
    request
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tags = request.form.get('tags', [], type=lambda x: x.strip().split(';') if x.strip() else [])
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The example shown can certainly be refined, but it illustrates how it works.